# EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI: Invalid User

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss7.x

I'm trying to invocations from a remote client using JNDI in JBOSS 7.1.1, but I get the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:54)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:45)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:74)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:302)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$200(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:196)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>       at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.InvocationExceptionResponseHandler$MethodInvocationExceptionResultProducer.getResult(InvocationExceptionResponseHandler.java:99)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:270)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:47)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:272)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:132)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:260)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:399)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:140)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
>       at $Proxy0.informarDados(Unknown Source)
>       at br.com.ciss.client.service.informacao.InformacaoServiceImpl.informarDados(InformacaoServiceImpl.java:224)
>       at br.com.ciss.client.agente.EnviaInformacaoMaquina.enviarInformacao(EnviaInformacaoMaquina.java:29)
>       at br.com.ciss.client.agente.EnviaInformacaoMaquina.main(EnviaInformacaoMaquina.java:49)
>   1325 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.AutoConnectionCloser  - Closing Remoting connection <1bde4>
>   1329 [Remoting "config-based-ejb-client-endpoint" task-2] INFO  org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation  - Channel Channel ID ec18d75d (outbound) of Remoting connection 007bc899 to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447 can no longer process messages
>   1426 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver  - Closing channelChannel ID ec18d75d (outbound) of Remoting connection 007bc899 to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
>   1427 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation  - Closing channel Channel ID ec18d75d (outbound) of Remoting connection 007bc899 to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
>   1428 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation  - Registering a re-connect handler org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.EJBClientContextConnectionReconnectHandler@a2220f for broken channel Channel ID ec18d75d (outbound) of Remoting connection 007bc899 to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447 in EJB client context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@c8376b
>   1433 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.AutoConnectionCloser  - Closing endpoint "config-based-ejb-client-endpoint" <1ecfe07>

I'm using the security mechanisms of jboss, and I have added the user through the add-user.bat also have the file jboss-ejb-client.properties with username and password and still get the exception. I followed the example set of the link:[EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI), the same works when I'm not using the security mechanisms, but when I use the security mechanisms the error occurs

What you're missing?

Comment: when you say that your using the security mechanisms do you mean the jaas?

Comment: ok, this is my scenario: I have two server applications (A and B), that communicate via JMS, both using JAAS for user authentication. EJBs for each system uses security JBOSS via @RolesAllowed ("ROLE_ADMIN"), works just fine so far, I have seen the JASS set up right, and added the 'ApplicationRealm'.

 The problem is in a third application, a client jar (swing application) that must communicate with the application B. In this third application, when I attempt to lookup remote EJB application B, the lookup to work but when I call a method that must use the EJB, the specified error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JndiLoginInitialContextFactory) will help you. Use this before you do the lookup so that you are logged in to the jboss